# PowerBI Api: Can I publish a report to another user's "My Workspace" if the user is within my organization?

Tags: c#, powerbi

My organization is attempting to figure out a path for reporting solutions using Power BI.  Currently we only have a couple of pro/premium per user licenses, and many users with free licenses.  We'd like to be able to have certain users create reports for the organization and have the free users be able to access the reports with minimal involvement on their part. So my question is, would I be able to use the power bi api to publish a report to another free user's "My Workspace" on power bi services for users within my organization without the need to have everyone's passwords? If it's not possible with the free versions, would it work if everyone had pro licenses?  I've seen in the api that there is the option to post to "My Workspace", I'm just curious if that requires the password for every user.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking how to work around the Power BI licensing model?

Comment: Embed the reports in a web app using app owns data model. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, assuming you are not required to have on-prem hosting:

1. Purchase Power BI Pro licenses for users that are creating content and using self-service analytics.
2. Add Power BI Premium capacity workspace to be able to distribute BI content to users who only need to consume. You are billed by capacity (computing resources allocated), not by users here. So you can have unlimited viewers/consumers.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: We don't have enough users to justify the $5000 monthly cost of the premium capacity workspace.  It sounds like this idea is not possible, which was all I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately if you are not at a scale where it is feasible to purchase capacity, your best route is to assign each creator/viewer a Pro/Premium licenses. I recommend you draw up cost-benefit analysis to show the value of purchasing the licenses. @Jason247 also mark question as answered if my answer helped you, cheers.